# Example for a covering map with not equal groups from different base points

Tags: algebraic-topology, examples-counterexamples, covering-spaces, fundamental-groups

I am looking for the examples of a covering map $p: E \to B$ that satisfies following:

Let $e_0$, $e_1$ be points of $p^{-1}(b_0)$ and $H_i=p_*(\pi_1(E,e_i))$

Then, $H_0$ and $H_1$ are not eqaul.

I think covering maps for $\mathbb R \to S^1$ or $S^1 \to S^1$ induce the equal groups.

What is an example of such a covering map?

Comment: You may want to look at this : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2972207/what-is-a-normal-covering-geometrically

Comment: You can only find an example if $E$ is not path connected. Otherwise a path connecting the two choices of basepoint of $E$ will lead to an isomorphism via the usual conjugation trick.

Comment: @CheerfulParsnip Thanks for your answer in advance. By the way, what does the usual conjugation trick mean? I know if there is a path between two basepoints then, the two groups are conjugate. But, is the conjugate equivalent to equal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $p:S^1 \sqcup S^1 \rightarrow S^1$. The map from first $S^1 $ to  $S^1 $ is $z \rightarrow z^n $ and from the second  $S^1 $ to  $S^1 $ is identity map. This is a covering map. 
Now say for $1\in S^1 $ if $e_0$ is a preimage of $1$ in the first $S^1 $, the corresponding $p_*$ will just be multiplication by $n $. For the second case it will be identity.

Comment: I don't see how this answers the OP since the map $p$ changes.

Comment: If I am not wrong, I think in one case the image will be $\n\mathbf {Z}$ and in the second case it will be just $\mathbf {Z}$

Comment: Yes, I agree that the images are different, but the OP asked to vary the basepoint not the map.

Comment: The domain is a disjoint union of two circles. The map p is defined on both the circles. On each circle it is continuous and a covering map. As their intersection is null, it is a covering map defined on the whole domain. I didn't give 2 different maps. It's a single map.

Comment: Ah, I see. I didn't read that right.