# Continuity of Lifts and Covering Spaces

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

Suppose that $A$ and $B$ are covering spaces of a $X$. Suppose that $f: A \to X$ and $g: B \to X$ are the associated covering maps. If I wanted to construct a lift $h: A \to B$ such that $g \circ h = f$, would $h$ have to be continuous? This is something that was not clear to me while reading Hatcher's Algebraic Topology book. I am inclined to say that it does not have to be as the definition on Page 60 does not specify continuity.

Edit: Thanks for clarifying the continuity doubt.

Suppose that $X = S^1 \vee S^1$, and $A$ and $B$ are covering spaces on the left and right (respectively) of the figure shown below ([image taken from here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2974531)) [image] In this case, no lift of the previously mentioned type would exist. Essentially, the issue is because the two bottom loops of A are replaced with curved directed edges of B. Even if we tried mapping the first half of either bottom loop of A to one of the curved edges and the second half of the same loop to the other curved edge, we would get a loop in B that contains a vertex that is not the starting/ending point. This vertex would be mapped to the "vertex" in $X$. In other words, there would exist a non-vertex point in a bottom loop of $A$ that would be mapped to a vertex in $X$ by $g \circ h$.

Is my thought process correct?

Comment: The map is assumed to be continuous - you're working in the category of topological spaces and continuous maps. (By the way, your question was originally tagged algebraic-**geometry** instead of algebraic-**topology**, so I fixed that for you.)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification and the edit. I have particular example that I would like to apply this updated information to. Is it recommended to create a separate question or update the existing question?

Comment: Well your question was already answered, and I doubt that it would be posted as an actual answer. So i'd say you could include the example here

Answer (score 1):

Your reasoning is pretty much correct. To make it "official" use the lifting criteria. That is, there is a lift if and only if $f_*( \pi_1(A)) \subseteq g_*(\pi_1(B))$?